# how to set size for pop up window in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow, window-resize

Hi I need to know the syntax for setting the size for pop up window in chrome extension
Here is the syntax that I have used to open a pop up window.Please help me to set the window's size.I meed to reduce the size.
Here is my syntax

```
chrome.windows.create({url : "userinfo.html"});
```

Please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
chrome.windows.create({url : "userinfo.html",type: "popup", height: 200, width:200});
```

refer http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html for all the available properties

Comment: Hi can you suggest the way to position this pop up window at center

Comment: you can use "top" and "left" properties to set the position

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS for me. Steps: 1. Open Google Chrome on fullscreen --> 2. Open a popup with chrome.windows.create . It will open a Popup in fullscreen.